# Prove that $\Vert T \Vert =\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert< 1}\Vert T x \Vert,\;\forall\;T\in B(X,Y).$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Prove that $\Vert T \Vert =\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert< 1}\Vert T x \Vert,\;\forall\;T\in B(X,Y).$

**Trial**

It suffices to show that $\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert< 1}\Vert T x \Vert=\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq  1}\Vert T x \Vert,$ since we have shown that [$\Vert T \Vert =\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq  1}\Vert T x \Vert.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044446/proving-that-vert-t-vert-sup-limits-vert-x-vert-leq-1-vert-t-x-vert)

Since $\{\|Tx\|:\|x \|<1 \}\subseteq \{\|Tx\|:\|x \|<1 \}$, then
$$\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert< 1}\Vert T x \Vert\leq \sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq  1}\Vert T x \Vert.$$
How then, can I show the other side

$$\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq  1}\Vert T x \Vert\leq \sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert< 1}\Vert T x \Vert ?$$
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: This is not true if $X=\{0\}$.

Comment: @dex why not? If $X=\{0\}$ then $T(x)=0$ for any $x$ in the open unit disk and also for any $x$ in the closed unit disk. No contradictions here. Anyway, this case is not too interesting because it is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the supremum of $||T(x)||$ when $||x||\leq 1$ is $M$. It is enough to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is $x\in X$ such that $||x||<1$ and $||T(x)||>M-\epsilon$. So let $\epsilon>0$. We know there is $y\in X$ such that $||y||\leq 1$ and $||T(y)||>M-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. If $||y||<1$ then we are done. Else, $||y||=1$. In that case pick a sequence $y_n\in X$ such that $||y_n||<1$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y_n\to y$. Since $T$ is a bounded operator it is continuous, hence $T(y_n)\to T(y)$. Any norm is continuous so $||T(y_n)||\to ||T(y)||$. So pick $x$ from the sequence such that the distance between $||T(x)||$ and $||T(y)||$ is smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and that's it.

Comment: Please, can you conclude? I can hardly get the conclusion of what you are trying to prove, although I understood the proof.

Comment: Conclusion: for each $\epsilon>0$ we got that there exists a vector $x\in X$ such that $||x||<1$ and $||T(x)||>M-\epsilon$. That means any number which is smaller than $M$ is not an upper bound of the set $\{||T(x)||: ||x||<1\}$, hence the supremum is at least $M$. And in the question itself you already showed that the supremum of this set is at most $M$. So it is equal to $M$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't still get you. Did you answer my question, by showing that $\sup\limits_{\| x\|\leq 1}\| Tx\|\leq \sup\limits_{\| x\|<1}\| Tx\|$? I still don't get your points. Could you put it more mathematically?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let's say $M=\sup\limits_{\| x\|\leq 1}$. So in that case your question was how to prove that $M\leq \sup\limits_{\| x\|<1}$. Well, this is what my answer proves.

Comment: Okay, let me go through. If I have anything to ask, I'll get back at you! Thanks, (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|x\| = 1$ and note $x_n := (1 - \frac{1}{n})x$ converges to $x$. I think you can then show $\|T x_n\| \to \|T x\|$.